# How to access GBoard clipboard manager without turning on 'Show suggestion strip'?

Tags: applications, keyboard, 9.0-pie, gboard

Is there anyway to access clipboard manager in google keyboard without enabling suggestion strip? It seems I can't find a shortcut or way to access it. I'm using the latest version from Playstore

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, the only way to access the clipboard manager is when the suggestion strip is enabled in Gboard settings. There are no shortcuts on the keyboard nor is there an option for it in the settings.